# How can I use dialog from a common class in android

Tags: android, android-activity, static, dialog, android-context

I use a static method from a common class in different activities. The method contains dialog. The dialog fires successfully from various activities. But when I declare the static dialog in the common class android studio warns me not to place Android context classes in static fields (a static reference to DialogChooser which has the field yes pointing to Button); this is a memory leak. How can I use this method containing a static dialog from the common class?

The dialog used in a common class

```
public class CommonUtility {

public static DialogChooser purchaseDialog;

public static void openDialog(Context context){
    purchaseDialog = new DialogChooser(context, context.getString(R.string.message), context.getString(R.string.text_yes), context.getString(R.string.text_no), new DialogClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onYesClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, ActivityForExample.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            purchaseDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNoClick(View view) {
           purchaseDialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCrossClick(View view) {
            purchaseDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    purchaseDialog.show();
}
```

}

My custom dialog class is

```
public class DialogChooser extends AppCompatDialog implements View.OnClickListener {

public String message;
public String yesText;
public String noText;
public Window window;
public Button yes, no, cross;
public TextView tvDialogTitle;
public DialogClickListener dialogClickListener;

public DialogChooser(Context activity, String message, String yesText, String noText, DialogClickListener dialogClickListener) {
    super(activity);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.dialogClickListener = dialogClickListener;
    this.message = message;
    this.yesText = yesText;
    this.noText = noText;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

    setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    window = this.getWindow();

    lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
    //This makes the dialog take up the full width
    lp.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    lp.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
    window.setAttributes(lp);

    yes = findViewById(R.id.btn_yes);
    no = findViewById(R.id.btn_no);
    cross = findViewById(R.id.btn_cross);
    tvDialogTitle = findViewById(R.id.txt_dialog);

    tvDialogTitle.setText(message);
    yes.setText(yesText);
    no.setText(noText);

    yes.setOnClickListener(this);
    no.setOnClickListener(this);
    cross.setOnClickListener(this);
  

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_yes) {
        dialogClickListener.onYesClick(v);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_no) {
        dialogClickListener.onNoClick(v);
    } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_cross) {
        dialogClickListener.onCrossClick(v);
    }

    dismiss();
}
```

}

Comment: Why keeping a reference to the dialog in the CommonUtility class? You can have the openDialog() method to return the created dialog and keep the reference in the Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't have `static` `Dialog` or any other class extending/containing `Context`, these are momery leaks, thats it. so your architecture/idea is wrong, you should return created dialog to `Activity`, which created it, and this `Activity` should dismiss it when gets destroyed (`onDestroy()`) or maybe even when goes to background (`onStop()`)

```
public static Dialog openDialog(Context context){
    DialogChooser purchaseDialog = ...
    ...
    Dialog d = purchaseDialog.create();
    d.show();
    return d;
}
```

summary after comments:

```
public class CommonUtility {

// comment/remove static dependency
//public static DialogChooser purchaseDialog;

public static void openDialog(Context context){
    DialogChooser purchaseDialog = ... // local dependency
    ...
    purchaseDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Where do I initialize purchaseDialog object of DialogChooser class?

Comment: keep it inside `openDialog` method (edited answer)

Comment: Thank you but it says required type dialog but provided void when I assign purchaseDialog object into Dialog d.

Comment: I've just noticed that you are using some cutom library, which provides `DialogChooser`. I don't see such class in official Android doc, can you link source of this class?

Comment: if your `DialogChooser` doesn't return `Dialog` instance, then just stay with `purchaseDialog.show();` at the end of method, but keep `DialogChooser` instance only locally and remove `public static DialogChooser purchaseDialog;` line

Comment: I have edited my code. I added my custom dialog class. Finally, I solved the problem. Your code and comments kept me on the right track to solving the problem. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score -1):

My updated `openDialog` method is

```
public static void openDialog(Context context, String msg){
    DialogChooser purchaseDialog = new DialogChooser(context, msg, context.getString(R.string.text_yes), context.getString(R.string.text_no), new DialogClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onYesClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, PurchasedClassActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(i);
            //purchaseDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNoClick(View view) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            //purchaseDialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCrossClick(View view) {
            //purchaseDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    purchaseDialog.show();
    //return purchaseDialog;
}
```

Where I just prevented me to dismiss the dialog inside the callback method and access my custom `DialogChooser` class as non-static.